# In R, different behavior between `is.list(x)` and `is(x,'list')`

Tags: r, inheritance, types, typechecking

What is the explanation for the following behavior?

```
is.list(data.frame()) ## TRUE
is(data.frame(),'list') ## FALSE
is(data.frame()) ## "data.frame" "list" "oldClass" "vector"
extends('data.frame','list') ## TRUE
inherits(data.frame(),'list') ## FALSE
```

Comment: another function with interesting info is `getClass('data.frame')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing S3 and S4 class conventions. `is` and `extends` are for S4 classes but these work with S3 ones because of the way these have been implemented. `inherits` was written for S3 classes and it is not intended to work with S4 objects with full compatibility.

`inherits` effectively compares the result of `class(x)` with the class you specify in the second argument. Hence

```
> class(data.frame())
[1] "data.frame"
```

doesn't contain `"list"` anywhere so fails.

Note also this from `?inherits`:

```
 The analogue of ‘inherits’ for formal classes is ‘is’.  The two
 functions behave consistently with one exception: S4 classes can
 have conditional inheritance, with an explicit test.  In this
 case, ‘is’ will test the condition, but ‘inherits’ ignores all
 conditional superclasses.
```

Another confusion is with the class of an object and the implementation of that object. Yes a data frame is a list as `is.list()` tells us, but in R's S3 class world, `data.frame()` is of class `"data.frame"` not `"list"`.

As for `is(data.frame(),'list')`, well it isn't of that specific class `"list"` hence the `FALSE`. What `is(data.frame())` does is documented in `?is`

```
Summary of Functions:

     ‘is’: With two arguments, tests whether ‘object’ can be treated as
          from ‘class2’.

          With one argument, returns all the super-classes of this
          object's class
```

Hence `is(data.frame())` is showing the classes that the `"data.frame"` class extends (in the S4 sense, not the S3 sense). This further explains the `extends('data.frame','list')` behaviour as in the S4 world, the `"data.frame"` class *does* extend the `"list"` class.